# Trying to find a specific WpfControl for use in Coded UI tests

Tags: c#, wpf, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to create some Coded UI tests to be used many times over a "set" of WPF controls. I can use the Coded UI test builder to create each test individually, but I am looking to create the "general" case, since each test is very similar, with slight modifications.

In order to create this general case, I need to be able to find (then click) a control given the parent (in this case, a `WpfWindow`; the control I am looking for is a few levels deep, but I want to be able to find the control regardless of depth). I have been able to find the control I'm looking for using `AutomationElement`, but coded UI doesn't seem to like it, and I am unable to click it once found.

I've tried using `GetChildren()` on the parent window and then recursively searching to find the control in question as well. I am using the `SearchProperties` to look for the `Name` and `ControlType` of the specific WPF control I'm looking for, but it doesn't look like everything has a `Name` and it fails out.

I've also tried just setting the `SearchProperties` for the specific control, but it throws an exception saying it cannot be found.

Any suggestions? Am I going about this the right way, or am I missing something fundamental?

An aside to this is: how "bad" is it to have similar Coded UI tests built with the Coded UI test builder? What I mean is, it seem wrong to create 800 different tests using the Coded UI Test Builder that all have the same first 5 steps (with minor differences based on where it is run).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I revisited the `AutomationElement` solution and was able to figure out the click portion.

```
public AutomationElement findControl(AutomationProperty propertyOfItem, string itemToSearchFor, System.Windows.Automation.ControlType controlType)
{
            Condition condition = new System.Windows.Automation.AndCondition(
                   new System.Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition(propertyOfItem, itemToSearchFor),
                   new System.Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, controlType));

            AutomationElement foundControl = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants | TreeScope.Children, condition);
            return foundControl;
}
```

The click portion gets the clickable point from `AutomationElement` and stores it in a `System.Windows.Point` and based on that creates a `System.Drawing.Point`. Then calls `Mouse.Click()` on that point.

Answer (score 0):

How we handled this is recording the controls but not the steps. You can then pass the control which is mapped in with full parent-parent-parent . . . -parent mapping into a method.

```
ControlB = genericControl(parentWindow,     
    "ControlType","Button","ControlName","Send");
TestOne(ControlB);
TestOne(ControlC);

public void TestOne(UITestControl control, string Value)
{ 
    //do stuff
    Mouse.Click(control);
    Assert.AreEqual(Value, control.GetProperty("InnerText"));
}
```

generic control:

```
public UITestControl genericControl(UITestControl parentWindow, String Property1, String Value1, String Property2, String Value2)
{
    UITestControl control = new UITestControl(parentWindow);
    control.TechnologyName = "MSAA";
    control.SearchProperties.Add(Property1, Value1, Property2, Value2);

    return control;
}
```

etc.

If each step is generic it should work.

ETA - you have to have some characteristics of the control you want to use. unless you want to use `FindAllMatchingControls` and loop through all the controls, or different types to filter the list, you have to have unique identifying info for each control.

Comment: I'm not quite sure this helps. Yes it's generic, but my issue is actually finding the specific control I want. 

The issue here is finding control to pass to `public void TestOne(UITestControl control, string Value)`

Comment: I see what you mean. I guess my next question is how to get a control with the full parent-parent-parent...-parent mapping when one or more parents are specific to the current run. For example, the end of my control(s) looks like this: `...UIBrowseTreeCustom.UITreeViewTree.UICNameTreeItem.UIItemTreeItem;` where `CName` refers to the name of the computer on which the Coded UI Test was built. I am going to try something then will get back.

Comment: Now we're at the heart of the matter!! In the properties window for an object you can change the search property to "Contains" from "Equals" so you can have the name = WindowParent123d to name.Contains(WindowParent) and it will find the match. You can also change/delete the window titles for a control.